# Laravel - bindings file for repositories

Tags: php, laravel, binding

So I have an App\bindings.php file that I have added to my composer.json file as so:

```
"autoload": {
    "files": [
        "app/bindings.php"
    ]
},
```

In this file I am trying to set up bindings for my repositories like so:

```
<?php 

function getRepoBinding($id)
{
    $repo = "{$id}Repository";

    $clientName = strtoupper(config('client.name'));
    $implementation = config('app.repo_implementation', 'Eloquent');
    $clientOverride = "App\Overrides\\{$clientName}\Repositories\\{$implementation}\\{$repo}";
    $repo = class_exists($clientOverride) ? $clientOverride : "App\Repositories\\{$implementation}\\{$repo}";
    return $repo;
}
// Repository Interface Bindings
dd(getRepoBinding('Contribution'));
App::bind('ContributionIneterface', getRepoBinding('Contribution'));
```

However, i run a `composer dump-auto` and try to run my application and I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function make() on null in /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php:54 
Stack trace: #0 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(158): app('config') 
#1 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/app/bindings.php(9): config('client.name') 
#2 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/app/bindings.php(16): App\getRepoBinding('Contribution') 
#3 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(55): require('/home/vagrant/C...') 
#4 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php(45): composerRequire03fe235c8b3156f0c5fcebbc0d696734('90f93262f3a0ac8...', '/home/vagrant/C...') 
#5 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/vendor/autoload.php(7): ComposerAutoloaderInit03fe235c8b3156f0c5fcebbc0d696734::getLoader() 
#6 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/bootstrap/autoload.php(17): require('/home/vagrant/C...') 
#7 /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/public/index.php(22): require('/home/vagrant/C...') 
#8 {main} thrown in /home/vagrant/Code/famsapi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php on line 54
```

It seems like it is having with the global config helper method...but im not sure how to fix that. Better yet, if you have an idea of how I can do this another way I am all ears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are loading that file before the application starts.

Use it inside your AppServiceProvider